# Selenium 2.0 Переадресация с одной страницы на другую

Tags: selenium

Здравствуйте знатоки Selenium, как мне совершить переадресацию с одной страницы на другую, как я понимаю с помощью метода get() класса WebDriver это не сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Переадресация в смысле просто перейти на другую страницу? Например, сначала работали на ya.ru, потом надо перейти на google.com? тогда всё верно:

```
driver.get('https://ya.ru/')
time.sleep(1)
driver.get('https://www.google.ru/')
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```